# Is it possible to make comments visible only to author and owner on Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, google-drive-sharing

I've been thinking about using Google Docs to share a novel with a few beta-readers because it is simpler than sending every one of them a separate text file and keeping track of the comments across files.

For this to work, though, I would need the comments of each reader to be visible only to them and to me, so they can't relapse into a "herd mentality". Each of them should read the novel and comment by themselves, with no influence from the others.

Is there any way to achieve this in Google Docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in Google Docs. All comments are visible to all commenters.

Comment: This is really unfortunate. I can't believe this wouldn't be a common scenario, like AT LEAST every beta-reading scenario, and perhaps many, many other workplace situations. Not just a herd-mentality problem, but good old-fashioned spam, where everyone sees every other comment which is completely irrelevant to them, and pops a valuable one-on-one intimacy bubble they thought they had with the author.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to hide the comments made by one commenter to other commenters. One alternative is that you use Google Classroom to make an assignment for beta-readers. You could set the assignment to create a copy of the document for each of them. This way, only you will be able to read the comments of all beta-readers.